# Можно ли узнать id перекрытого div другим div?

Tags: css, jquery

Есть два div. Один наложен на другой. У первого z-index 1, у второго z-index 2.
Можно ли узнать id перекрытого div?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: каким образом? на клик? на наведении мыши? на инициализацию страницы, на какое действие вам нужно это узнать?)

Comment: в том то и дело, наведением или кликом узнать легко, а возможно ли дивом, перекрывающим другой див :)

Comment: Вас спрашивают, по какому событию должна произойти проверка

Comment: Stranger in the Q По клику на button например